# Class definition in java

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point, public

I'm new to Java and i want a refinement:
First of all,i am not sure if i can have 2 classes in the same file.
My question is what is each class when you see this sequence of code:

```
class Something {    
    //code here
} //end of class Something

public class SomethingElse {
    //NO code here!!!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //code of main here
    }//end of main
}
```

What's the role of the class Something Else and why there is no code inside?I know that is a very stupid question but there are some details that i don't really get and i want some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have just one public class per file, and the file must have the same name of the class. But you can have other private classes that just the file class will see. For example:

File `Something.java`

```
public class Something {
  //Something can access SomethingElse's doSomething method.

  private class SomethingElse {
    public void doSomething() {
    }
  }
}

class SomethingToo {

}
```

File `OtherSomething.java`

```
public class OtherSomething {
  //OtherSomething cannot access SomethingElse's doSomething method.
  //But can access SomethingToo, if they are in the same package
}
```

Comment: This isn't true.  OtherSomething can access the doSomething() method by instantiating a SomethingElse object.  There will be issues in compilation sometimes if it does not actually reference the Something class though.

Comment: Half true. OtherSomething can access stuff in SomethingElse as long as both classes are in the same package. Otherwise SomethingElse and all its methods will be hidden (except through reflection).

Comment: You can also have the OtherSomething as being a public static/ non static class of the Something class.

Comment: Making SomethingElse private will not make it invisible to OtherSomething if they are in the same package, so this answer is still a little misleading / incorrect.  The private makes it private to the package, and removing private will allow classes from other packages to use it (if they import correctly).

Comment: @John private is a illegal modifier in that case. I mean to put this inside `Something` class.

Answer (score 4):

You can have more than one class per file, but only one class can be `public` and its name must match the name of the file (e.g. `public MyClass` in MyClass.java).

The public class of a file will be visible to the *outside world*, and in particular if the class has a `public static main(String[] args)` method, it can be used to start an application.

In your case for example, once you have compiled your file using javac, you will get files `Something.class` and `SomethingElse.class`.

Using the command `java SomethingElse` will tell the Java Virtual Machine to do the following:

- Find the SomethingElse class, which must be in the SomethingElse.class file
- call the main method, matching the signature I pasted above on this class (and putting any given argument in the `args` array).

You cannot call `java Something` because the class isn't public and doesn't have a main method. But other classes in your program (and in particular, SomethingElse, can use your Something class).

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple classes defined in a same file. However there should only one class defined as public and file name will be that public class name.

In the `No code here!!!` you can have class variables and methods defined. Your main() is one such example.

Answer (score 0):

In the above file, there are two classes SomethingElse (public) and Something. Now, this is normally done when the non-public class is called internally by the public class. Also, in the above code fragment, SomethingElse seems to be a 'driver' class. In other words, it does not have any functionality/data of its own, but is used to execute (drive) other classes (probably Something in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can have nested classes, but two separate, public classes are not allowed.  Each public class should be in it's own file named the same as the class.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to have 2 classes in the same file, its considered bad practice.  Besides the decreased readability, it will eventually become difficult to find out where that class declaration actually took place.  Plus, if you declare a variable relating to the class, but not the class sharing the .java name, javac will most likely have issues compiling.

If you have to do it, make sure the only place you are using the second class is within the class sharing the .java name. (E.g. only use a `Something` object within the `SomethingElse` class).  Otherwise, separate all your classes into separate .java files.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can have 2 or more classes in single Java file.
The only condition is only one class will contain main method with signature(`public static void main(String[] args)`).
And only one public class will be there. And with that public class name you can save your file - the file name has to match the name of the public class.

Comment: "The only condition is only one class will contain main method". That is not correct.